# Trying to pulsate with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, image, hyperlink

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../JQuery/jquery.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("img").click(function () {
            $(this).effect("pulsate", { times:3 }, 2500);
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have a link to an external .js sheet on my hard drive which is a compressed file of v2.0.0 that I copy-pasted into blank .js file and saved.

I am pretty sure that link is correct as far as incorporating the jQuery file into my document. I think the coding may be wrong.

I have included the code above just before the closing `</body>` tag in my document verbatim as you can see, but when I upload everything to my host and try out the website, the images I am trying to pulsate will not pulsate. They're static and I can't figure out why.

Comment: You should use the debugging tools in your browser to see if (1) there are any 404 errors from loading jquery and (2) there are any Javascript errors.  Also, I think pulsate is a jquery-ui effect, so you might need to include jquery-ui into your page.

Comment: if you are going to play with javascript...at least learn how to look for errors in a browser console. A 10 second check will save you a lot of time guessing

Comment: Hello @user2325723, Did my answer help you out at all?

Answer (score 0):

Remember, `pulsate` is part of the JqueryUI library. Be sure to include jQueryUI along with jQuery.

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AYDFj/).

Source: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Pulsate

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
function pulsateElement(element){
    element.removeClass('pulsate');
    setTimeout(function(){
        element.addClass('pulsate');
        setTimeout(function(){
            pulsateElement(element);
        },500);
    },700);
}
```